# In Pubspec.lock file razor_pay flutter is having version 1.3.2 vs in Pubspec.yaml its 1.3.2

Tags: flutter, dependencies, pubspec.yaml, flutter-razorpay

In pubspec.lock the version is : "1.3.4" ,in pubspec.yml the version is  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.2
i tried deleting lock file then running pub get but still it goes to 1.3.4 , i want to use only the version 1.3.2

i tried running pub get , still its showing 1.3.4 in pubspec.lock file.
i tried deleting the lock file then get pub but still its showing in lock file 1.3.2, where as in pubspec.yml its showing 1.3.2
i want to use 1.3.2 version only
and why flutter is changing the  lock file version and not updating it to 1.3.4 as same as pubspec.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having:

```yaml
dependencies:
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.2
```

in your `pubspec.yaml` file does *not* mean to use only version 1.3.2; it means use a version that is expected to be *backwards-compatible* with version 1.3.2 based on [semantic versioning](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/versioning#semantic-versions).  This is explained by the [documentation for caret syntax](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax).

If you want to use version 1.3.2 and *only* version 1.3.2, remove the caret:

```yaml
dependencies:
  razorpay_flutter: 1.3.2
```

However, if you're doing that because of some incompatibility with version 1.3.4, then you should report that to the package maintainer.